# In NodeJS, how should environment bundles be provided to globally installed bins?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I install with `npm install -g`, which results in a js file being placed in `/usr/bin`. Is it recommended to use a `.env` file in this case? Or what's a better way of providing environment variables to a command-line script?